# Application Launcher for snap applications not working from Dash

Tags: launcher, snap, .desktop

I used FastX to connect to my work-computer running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and am trying to install multiple apps, e.g. Skype. I don't have sudo permissions, however I was able to install it through

```
snap install skype
```

Unfortunately, this installation has several problems. The first is that apparently FastX sets `XAUTHORITY` to a path which `snapd` ignores. As a workaround our IT suggested

```
cp "$XAUTHORITY" ~/fastx_authority; export XAUTHORITY=~/fastx_authority
```

which worked well. I am now able to start Skype through

```
snap run skype
```

or

```
/snap/bin/skype
```

However, I wanted to add it to the Launcher. Therefore I copied

```
cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/skype_skypeforlinux.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

I confirmed that this works through

```
gtk-launch skype_skypeforlinux.desktop
```

which successfully opens Skype (though there are still some errors printed in the terminal). However, opening the Dash through the Super-key, typing Skype (which is properly found) and pressing enter does nothing than turn the mouse into a loading wheel for a few seconds. I modified the `.desktop` file to `Terminal=true`. Then I try again to launch Skype through the Dash and now, for a split second, a terminal opens, showing the following:

```
+ [ -f /home/user/snap/skype/common/.config/skypeforlinux/settings.json ]
+ export SKYPE_LOGS=/home/user/snap/skype/203/logs
+ [ ! -d /home/user/snap/skype/203/logs ]
+ exec /snap/skype/203/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux
No protocol specified
[43899:0304/164128.030408:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1400)] Unable to open X display.
[0304/164128.031910:ERROR:scoped_ptrace_attach.cc(27)] ptrace: Permission denied (13)
```

I also get the same behavior with a `.desktop` file simply containing

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Skype
Exec=/snap/bin/skype
Icon=/snap/skype/203/meta/gui/skypeforlinux.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

I also get a similar behavior with Evince, which I also installed through snap. However, here the terminal stays empty and just vanishes after a split second.

I actually don't mind starting Skype through the terminal since that's a one-time thing. What I really want to do is associate PDF files to open with the Evince installation.

Note that custom `.desktop` files generally work, the problem seems to be with snap apps.

Any ideas?